# What does the error message mean when using lm linear regression command - error in the model.frame.default... variable lengths differ?

Tags: r, lm, variable-length

I tried to run a bivariate regression. I want to examine the association between level of education (IV) with views on immigration (DV). The DV is an interval level variable and the IV a dummy variable. I label the regression as reg. The code is as follows:

```
>reg <-lm(immig.view~edu.degree.level,df1)
>Error in model.frame.default(formula = immig.view ~ edu.degree.level,  : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'edu.degree.level')
```

I'm completely stuck. Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you dput(head(df1,10)) and paste the output as part of your post? then others can reproduce the error and suggest where the problem lies

Comment: Likely one of the variables in your formula is a column of `df1` and the other is a separate vector with different length.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius exactly this! Many thanks!

Comment: @StupidWolf I started over and now the model runs. Many thanks for the suggestion (and also showing me a new command) as I will do this going forward (this was my first post).